# How to find a shortest name (string) of the same image with different naming

Tags: php, regex, string, image

I have a problem that I don´t know how to approach. 
I have a folder of different images. There are different names for the same images. I need to find the shortest one.

One image can have different names. For example like this:

- clownfish.jpg, clownfish-1024x658.jpg, clownfish-150x150.jpg 
     => need to find **clownfish.jpg**

Another image:

- b800-768x575.jpg, b800-4.jpg, b800.jpg => I need to find **b800.jpg**

And another image:

- agility_3.jpg, agility_3-45x45.jpg => I need to find **agility_3.jpg**

All images are in the same folder. How can I differentiate between those images and select the group of same images and find the shortest one?
I´m sorry but I don´t know how to explain it better. 
Any ideas?

For doing this I will use php.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: What about `b800-768x575.jpg` and `768x575.jpg` and `768.jpg` and `x.jpg`?

Comment: I need to find the same pattern for the group of the same image. For example image named b800-4.jpg and b800-768x575.jpg have b800 as the same pattern. I thought about regex but don´t have idea how to implement it. Or use php to find substring in the different namings

Comment: for the clownfish.jpg, clownfish-1021x658.jpg the pattern  clownfish

Comment: How can I detect common substrings in a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function to compare the strings and use that to find the smallest similar string.
Comments in code below.

You can use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the array of files.

```
$arr= ["clownfish.jpg", "clownfish-1024x658.jpg", "clownfish-150x150.jpg",
"b800-768x575.jpg", "b800-4.jpg", "b800.jpg",
"agility_3.jpg", "agility_3-45x45.jpg"];

foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    foreach($arr as $key2 => $item2){
        if($key != $key2){// make sure we don't compare the same items
            $length = min(strlen($item), strlen($item2))-4; // lenght of the smallest string - ".jpg"
            if(levenshtein(substr($item,0,$length), substr($item2,0,$length), 1,1,0) == 0){ //is it the same file 
                $len = [strlen($item) => $item, strlen($item2) => $item2]; // make a associative array with lenght as key
                $minkey = min(array_keys($len)); // find the smallest of them
                $new[] = $len[$minkey]; // add the smallest to the new array
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump(array_unique($new)); // remove duplicates
```

Output of the above

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "clownfish.jpg"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "b800.jpg"
  [8]=>
  string(13) "agility_3.jpg"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/q52vs

---

Below in comments it seems OP wants to search for a file, if not found find original name from folder.

```
$find = "clownfish-1024x658.jpg";

var_dump(in_array($find, $arr)); // does file exist in array
foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    $length = min(strlen($item), strlen($find))-4; // lenght of the smallest string - ".jpg"
    if(levenshtein(substr($item,0,$length), substr($find,0,$length), 1,1,0) == 0){ //is it the same file 
        $len = [strlen($item) => $item, strlen($find) => $find]; // make a associative array with lenght as key
        $minkey = min(array_keys($len)); // find the smallest of them
        $new[] = $len[$minkey]; // add the smallest to the new array
    }
}

var_dump(array_unique($new));
```

https://3v4l.org/HRKMa

Comment: This is really interesting. Looks like the closest solution to my problem. If I have a string like 'clownfish-1024x658.jpg' how can I find that the image 'clownfish' already exists in the file? Would I look for a substring ?

Comment: I have to take in mind that the shortest one is the original image that was not resized. Then in the file are different sizes of the same image. How could I find out  from a long string like clownfish_1024x658.jpg is already in the file?

Comment: Click on the link above and see the output. I have the example files you mentioned in the code running, and it seems to work as far as I can see

Comment: I assume that I can check if a string in the array is a substring of my given string. You helped me a lot. Thank you

Comment: @Roman I don't understand the problem. The output is the shortest filenames of the input array that is similar according to levenshtein function.

Comment: My problem is that I need to get an image name from url like ?image=clownfish-1024x658.jpg and then check if the image already exists in the file. If it doesn´t I need to find the original image in the file that can be clownfish.jpg and then from this image I will resize it.

Comment: Ok just use in_array() and it will return true or false if the file exists in the scandir array

Comment: @Roman it seems you asked the wrong question then. Here is what you need. I removed the $find from the array, and the output is the original filename according to the function. https://3v4l.org/HRKMa

Comment: thats very useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, first of all, let us extract all the images from the directory sorted.

```
files = sorted(os.listdir(images))
```

What will happen is that the files with the shortest one will come first. For example, `b800-768x575.jpg, b800-4.jpg, b800.jpg` 
will now get sorted to come in the following order:

`b800.jpg, b800-4.jpg, b800-768x575.jpg`

To find all the groups with the shortest one, we will iterate.

```
select = files[0]
shortest = [select]
for file in files:
    if select in file:
        continue
    else:
        select = file
        shortest.append(select)
```

The `shortest` will now contain your required files

Comment: There are some loopholes in the solution, which I think may only get solved as we get more information about the different names of images.

Comment: This does not look like PHP, although it does look like the right approach.