# PHP function in_array doesn't recognize diacritic

Tags: php, arrays, image, diacritics, scandir

I have a code that runs through files and getting all images.

```
$img = '/srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2018_07_DogOwner_VS_CatOwner_655x368_NL-500x281.jpg';
$dir = preg_replace('#[^/]*$#', '', $img); 
$image_files = scandir($dir); 
$image_name = @array_pop(explode('/', $img));
$find = $image_name;
var_dump(in_array($find, $image_files));
```

In this example I run only through one image. This code returns true. The problem is when I have an image that has for example german signs (hundezubehör-für-sommer.jpg).

```
$img = '/srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/hundezubehör-für-sommer.jpg';
```

This returns false. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

EDITED:
I have asked this question few days ago: [How to find a shortest name (string) of the same image with different naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210080/how-to-find-a-shortest-name-string-of-the-same-image-with-different-naming). The solution to this is here: https://3v4l.org/T7lfU. The problem I think is when I run the code from scandir then It can't find the diacritic.

Comment: The problem is definitely not in `in_array`. Dump the function arguments (`$find` and `$image_files`) and you will see that the function works correctly.

Comment: P.S. A simpler way to check that the image exists: `file_exists($img)`

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: My PHP version is 7.2.9-1

Comment: You could try `$image_files = array_map("utf8_encode", scandir($dir));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in_array` function works despite the strings alphabet. I guest the problem happens because your PHP file and filesystem use different encodings therefore the value read by `scandir` has another encoding therefore it differs from the `$img` value written in the code.

Try to convert the encoding of the `scandir` result to make it match the PHP file encoding. For example:

```
// ...
$image_files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($image_files as &$file) {
    $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251');
}
// ...
var_dump(in_array($find, $image_files));
```

Replace `UTF-8` with the PHP file encoding and `Windows-1251` with your filesystem encoding.

Comment: the code runs on ubuntu. Does the encoding make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with storing multi-byte characters like `ö` and `ü` into a PHP file.

You can try interpreting the string as multi-byte:

```
$img = utf8_encode('/srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/hundezubehör-für-sommer.jpg');
```

Encoding, then decoding to make it safer:

```
$img = html_entity_decode('/srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/hundezubeh&ouml;r-f&uuml;r-sommer.jpg');
```

Or backslash the entities:

```
$img = "/srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/hundezubeh\303\266r-f\303\274r-sommer.jpg";
```